# PDF Annotation for iOS Using a Mouse

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ios, pdf

I am building an iOS application which consumes PDF documents and displays them to a user on their device, I need to allow the user to be able to interact with the content of the PDF by placing buttons over sections of the PDF.

To do this I need the coordinates of where the button should be placed within the PDF file view.

My initial thoughts were a web application using Javascript, PHP and MySQL would need to be created to allow my client to 'Draw' the buttons on to the PDF's and that this process would generate the coordinates needed and save them in a database.

After A LOT of googling I haven't found anything that does what I need so it looks like I will have to build something but I am stuck as what and where to start.

So the question is does anyone know of or can suggest a solution to the above that might get me started down the right path?

*N.B. I did ask a similar question but got marked down for vagueness so I have re asked here with more detail.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually built a system very similar to this, although I can't share the code with you. What I can do is tell you how it worked.

As you have suggested, a web app would let you place items where you wanted them, and then this was bundled up into a JSON file that described the locations of each item in points. We then rendered the PDFs using a CATiledLayer inside a scrollview and placed the rendered buttons/assets on top.

I think the best way to approach it would be to think about how to achieve it on the client-side, and then move to the server-side once you're happy with how things are being displayed/rendered using dummy data. How are you currently displaying your PDFs? If you're using a `UIWebView` things are going to be a lot harder.

Comment: Thanks for this I am using the PageViewController method for the PDF with some extras ;), is the solution something someone could purchase?

Comment: Perhaps there are other providers that have it - I'm afraid the stuff I worked on was part of my day job, and proprietary / not publicly available (it was also created before the PageViewController existed!). If you're using a page view controller you should be able to take the same approach, as you have direct access to the view hierarchy.

Comment: ah ok thats a shame do you know of any providers I'd rather avoid loads of dev if I can

Comment: Or even could you point me at the web technologies used in the web side frameworks etc?